# Deploying ear application on Weblogic 12 while i get an Exception : Unable to load a class that is specified in your ejb-jar.xml

Tags: java, runtime-error, ejb, weblogic12c

I have being searching for a solution to this problem for sometime now.
my application running on weblogic 10 box where it is using 1.5 jdk, and  i'm required to upgrade this weblogic 10 box to weblogic 12 using 1.7 jdk for now. this process was successfully done. and also asked to upgrade the application build script to use 1.7 jdk for 1.5 jdk too and that was all successfully done and the new ear package depend on the ejb jar that being build by 1.5 jdk. the the problem  come when i'm deploying an application now new weblogic 12 box. i am getting this Exception :

weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.DeploymentDescriptorException: [EJB:015025]Unable to load a class that is specified in your ejb-jar.xml:
    com.unibasex.bld.impl.ClassNameEJB.
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:175)
            at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:170)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
            at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
            at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
            at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    Caused by: weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.DeploymentDescriptorException: [EJB:015025]Unable to load a class that is specified in your ejb-jar.xml: com.unibasex.bld.impl.ClassNameEJB.
            at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.DeploymentInfoImpl.initializeBeanInfos(DeploymentInfoImpl.java:465)
            at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.DeploymentInfoImpl.(DeploymentInfoImpl.java:226)
            at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.prepare(EJBDeployer.java:700)
            at weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.prepare(EJBModule.java:439)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
            at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
            at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
            ... 8 more

```
and  this is the structure of my application 
myapp-56
├───myapp-ear
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main
│   │       ├───application
│   │       │   └───META-INF
│   │       └───resources
│   │           └───META-INF
│   ├───target
│   │    ├───classes
│   │    │   └───META-INF
│   │    ├───maven-archiver
│   │    ├───test-classes
│   │    └───myapp-56.01.00.00
│   │        └───META-INF
│   │
│   │
│   ├───pom.xml
│   │
│   ├───maven-build.xml
│   │
│   └───build.xml
│
├───myapp-ejb
│   ├───src
│   │   └───main
│   │       └───java
│   │           └───com
│   │               └───unibasex
│   │                   └───wom
│   ├───target
│   │    ├───classes
│   │    │   └───com
│   │    │       └───unibasex
│   │    │           └───wom
│   │    ├───dependency
│   │    ├───generated-sources
│   │    │   └───annotations
│   │    ├───maven-archiver
│   │    └───test-classes
│   ├───pom.xml
│   │
│   ├───maven-build.xml
│   │
│   └───build.xml
├───myapp-web
│    ├───src
│    │   └───main
│    │       ├───com
│    │       │   └───unibasex
│    │       │       └───wom
│    │       ├───java
│    │       │   └───com
│    │       │       └───unibasex
│    │       │           └───wom
│    │       ├───resources
│    │       └───webapp
│    │           ├───WEB-INF
│    │           └───wsdls
│    ├───target
│    │     ├───classes
│    │     │   └───com
│    │     │       └───unibasex
│    │     │           └───wom
│    │     ├───generated-sources
│    │     │   └───annotations
│    │     ├───maven-archiver
│    │     ├───test-classes
│    │     ├───wom-wfmr-web
│    │     │   └───WEB-INF
│    │     │       └───lib
│    │     └───myapp-web-56.01.00.00
│    │         ├───META-INF
│    │         └───WEB-INF
│    │             └───classes
│    │                 └───com
│    │                     └───unibasex
│    │                         └───wom
│    ├───pom.xml
│    │
│    ├───maven-build.xml
│    │
│    └───build.xml
│
├───pom.xml
│
├───myapp-build.cmd
│
├───maven-build.xml
│
└───build.xml

and my application do have application.xml too. 
my question is what may coz this exception and how can i fix it. 



I have tried stopping the server and delete the server cache and the server logs 
then start it again still i got this ear. then tried to include ejb that this new application  depend no but still failed to solve this problem and writing all the ejbs jar is not the option the new ear have to run parallel with the old ear on weblogic 10 for other high level reasons. 
any help on ideas on how i can solve this problem? please guys help me no this problem i'm out of ideas i have try reading documection on weblogic and ejb xml too. 

and this my ear pom.xml
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <release-version>56.01.00.00</release-version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myapp.app56</groupId>
        <artifactId>app56-interface</artifactId>
        <version>56.01.00.00</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myapp.app56</groupId>
    <artifactId>app56-ear</artifactId>
    <version>56.01.00.00</version>
    <name>app56--ear</name>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.app56</groupId>
            <artifactId>app56-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.app56</groupId>
            <artifactId>app56-web</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>msg_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>core_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.bd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bd_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.lmed</groupId>
            <artifactId>lmed_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.docman</groupId>
            <artifactId>doc_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.myapp.elogs</groupId>
            <artifactId>elogs_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.csi</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsi_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>wo_ejb</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>adm_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>adm_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cfy_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>cfy_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>csu_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>csu_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>doc_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>doc_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>elogs_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>elogs_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>lmed_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>lm_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wfm_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>wfm_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ticket_war</groupId>
            <artifactId>ticket_war</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myapp.myapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>wo</artifactId>
            <version>56.01.00.00</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <version>6</version>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
</project>
```

This and pom xml my application ear 
weblogic.application.ModuleException: weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.DeploymentDescriptorException: [EJB:015025]Unable to load a class that is specified in your ejb-jar.xml: com.unibasex.core.event.impl.EventHubEJB

Comment: did you check for com.unibasex.core.event.impl.EventHubEJB in your ejb jar ?

Comment: Yes I did and is inside the jar